# GWT RequestFactory ValueProxy Relations

Tags: hibernate, gwt, orm, requestfactory

Say I have a database, with types `A` and `B`. `A` is an `EntityProxy` which contains a list of `B`, and `B` is a `ValueProxy`. I useGWT's RequestFactory to query `A` by id. When I query for an `A` using RequestFactory, I can access the list of `B` like so: `A.getB()`, since `B` is a `ValueProxy'.

Question: is the `B` list actually queried and downloaded to the client at the time I query for `A`, or only when I call `getB()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no lazy-loading: you ask for "A with Bs", you get "A with Bs", if you ask only for A (because you don't use `.with("b")` on your `Request`), you'll get only A, and you'll have to ask for Bs later.

See it as the *principle of least surprise*.

Note that getting the Bs from your database (you tagged the question with Hibernate, JPA and ORM, so...) is a different story. It depends how you manage your EntityManager session and JPA entities' lifecycle. It might very well be the case that the Bs are loaded from the database even though they're not being sent to the client.

Comment: Does `with(String)` work with both Value and Entity proxies? IMO, Google's docs aren't clear why exactly you would want to use a Value proxy instead of an Entity proxy.

Comment: `.with()` is only needed for entity proxies. A ValueProxy has no _identity_, by definition, so transferring only part of it would mean you lose some data (so everything is always sent). With an EntityProxy, you can request different fields from the same entity (because it is _identifiable_) at different points in time (obviously, you might have them coming from different _versions_ of the entity, if it's been updated in the mean time). Only an EntityProxy can be _partially loaded_, and with an entity, only a diff of changes is sent from client to server.